# Cannot Assign 'Access B2B Commerce Admin Settings' Permission Set in Preview Org

Tags: permission-sets, b2b-commerce, cloudcraze

I am trying to install and test some features of B2B Commerce (Cloud Craze) in a preview org for the upcoming Salesforce Winter '21 release. (I am the admin of my preview org)

I have my preview org setup and I managed to install the B2B Commerce connector. However when I try to access the 'CC Admin' page I get the following error:

[image: Error Accessing CC Admin page]

I went into the 'Users' page in 'Setup' and I was able to assign myself the 'B2B Commerce Admin' set but when I try to assign the 'Access B2B Commerce Admin Settings' set I get the following error:
[image: Error assigning permission set]

I notice that in another org we use that the 'B2B Permission Set License' is available, but in the preview org, this is not an option.

I'm not sure how to proceed here, this is a complete blocker for me as I need to be able to install this package to carry out some testing for the upcoming release. Thanks for any help/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we had to open a ticket with salesforce to get this license added. There was no other way around this.